# Content Web Form not permitting to add content

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-3.5

This is the code of a nested master page in my project:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Presentation_Layer/Pages/home.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="cmsNestedMasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="livetest.Presentation_Layer.Pages.cmsNestedMasterPage" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">

</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <div id="divMenuSideBarLeft" class="MainSideBar1Div" style="top: 2px" 
        title="LiveTest CMS Menu">
    </div>

 <div id="divCmsContent" class="MainContentDiv" title="divCmsContent" 
        style="background-color: ButtonFace; width: 791px; left: 203px; position:relative; top: -602px;">
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

I have following queries:

1. The first `ContentPlaceHolder` `ContentPlaceHolderID="head"`, what is it for? Both the `ContentPlaceHolder`s were automatically added when I added this nested master page to my project.
2. In the second `ContentPlaceHolder` with `ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1"`, I added two `div`s. One is to display a side-bar on the left and the other is where I am going to show forms for entry. The problem is that when I added a new Web Content Form and linked it to this master page, it has only one pre-written line:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#"
    MasterPageFile="~/Presentation_Layer/Pages/cmsNestedMasterPage.master" 
    AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="BookEntry.aspx.cs" 
    Inherits="livetest.Presentation_Layer.Pages.CMS.BookEntry" %>
```

The code is not showing any `ContentPlaceHolder`s. Even if I try to add one, it gives error:

> The page has one or more `<asp:Content>` controls that do not correspond with `<asp:ContentPlaceHolder>` controls in the Master page.

How to rectify this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `ContentPlaceHolders` to the nested `MasterPage` inside the `Content` elements. eg

MasterPage 1:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

Nested MasterPage:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

    <div id="divMenuSideBarLeft" class="MainSideBar1Div" style="top: 2px" title="LiveTest CMS Menu">
    </div>

    <div id="divCmsContent" class="MainContentDiv" title="divCmsContent" style="background-color: ButtonFace; width: 791px; left: 203px; position:relative; top: -602px;">
       <-- Content on page goes inside this ContentPlaceHolder -->
       <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cphCmsDiv" runat="server">
       </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>

</asp:Content>
```

Then add the corresponding `Content` items to the page (they will be added automatically for new pages):

```
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphCmsDiv" runat="server">

</asp:Content>
```

Comment: This means that the ContentPlaceHolderID shown above corresponds to the Nested Master Page.

Comment: @RPK - yes cphCmsDiv corresponds to the ID of the ContentPlaceHolder in the nested masterpage. Edited my answer to show a more complete example